# Django robot.txt error

Tags: django

I'm trying to disable all web crawlers coming to my development server for a test purposes by using robot.txt

when I input 127.0.0.1:8000/robot.txt into the browser . Why doesn't the robot.txt appear in my browser?

```
Page not found (404)
127.0.0.1:8000/robot.txt
```

urls.py:

```
  from django.http import HttpResponse

  (r'^robots\.txt$', lambda r: HttpResponse("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /", mimetype="text/plain")),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `robot.txt` instead of `robots.txt`.

You should access `http://localhost/127.0.0.1:8000/robots.txt`

Comment: rohan can I ask u , the way i'm using robots.txt via urls . Is this a good way to disable all crawlers from reaching my site?

Comment: All you're doing here is posting a message to web crawlers that you'd really like them not to crawl your site. There's no enforcement of this, the crawler can ignore your robots.txt altogether.

But as a method of returning a robots.txt, this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

by the way it should be in urls.py not in views.py.

like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^robots\.txt$', lambda r: HttpResponse("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /", mimetype="text/plain"))
)
```